# Extracting values from ADF-test with loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am modelling with data set uschange from fpp2 package and I performing  Augmented Dickey-Fuller unit root test (ADF test), with vars package. In this example I have five series with names "Consumption"  "Income" ,  "Production",  "Savings" and  "Unemployment".You can see code below:

```
#CODE
library(fpp2)
library(vars)

MY_DATA<-data.frame(uschange)
MY_ADF_TESTS=apply(MY_DATA,2,function(x){
  return(
    list(
      #Constant 
      summary(ur.df(x, type = "drift",selectlags = c("BIC"))),
      summary(ur.df(diff(x), type = "drift",selectlags = c("BIC"))),
      #Trend
      #Constant 
      summary(ur.df(x, type = "trend",selectlags = c("BIC"))),
      summary(ur.df(diff(x), type = "trend",selectlags = c("BIC")))
      #summary(ur.df(x, type = "none",selectlags = c("BIC"))) 
    )
  )
})
```

Structure of this list you can see below:

[image]

[image]

So next step should be extract  test statistics and critical values from each series in this list and put into table. Test statistics and critical values are located in this location you can see in code below for the first series "Consumption"

```
MY_ADF_TESTS$Consumption[[1]]@teststat[1]
MY_ADF_TESTS$Consumption[[1]]@cval[3:3]

MY_ADF_TESTS$Consumption[[2]]@teststat[1]
MY_ADF_TESTS$Consumption[[2]]@cval[3:3]

MY_ADF_TESTS$Consumption[[3]]@teststat[1]
MY_ADF_TESTS$Consumption[[3]]@cval[3:3]
  
MY_ADF_TESTS$Consumption[[4]]@teststat[1]
MY_ADF_TESTS$Consumption[[4]]@cval[3:3]
```

So can anybody help how to do this with for loop for each five series  and put into one table with two columns.First which can contain data from teststat and second which contain cval data for each five series   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` for `MY_ADF_TESTS` and `sapply` for each list within `MY_ADF_TESTS`

```
lapply(MY_ADF_TESTS, function(x) t(sapply(x, function(y) 
                     c(testset = y@teststat[1], cval = y@cval[3:3]))))


#$Consumption
#        testset  cval
#[1,]  -6.165438 -2.88
#[2,] -16.489124 -2.88
#[3,]  -6.312517  8.43
#[4,] -16.443306  8.43

#$Income
#        testset  cval
#[1,]  -9.215409 -2.88
#[2,] -17.981296 -2.88
#[3,]  -9.328318  8.43
#[4,] -17.933000  8.43

#$Production
#        testset  cval
#[1,]  -7.006126 -2.88
#[2,] -13.423726 -2.88
#[3,]  -7.058146  8.43
#[4,] -13.389136  8.43

#$Savings
#       testset  cval
#[1,] -11.06383 -2.88
#[2,] -17.70920 -2.88
#[3,] -11.03983  8.43
#[4,] -17.66052  8.43

#$Unemployment
#        testset  cval
#[1,]  -5.784886 -2.88
#[2,] -12.754683 -2.88
#[3,]  -5.771049  8.43
#[4,] -12.725781  8.43
```